# Referring to "this" in event function while still being able to remove the event TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, keyboard-events

I am making this game in TypeScript, and trying to add and remove a "keydown" event. The event function is referring to "this", witch is the document, but i am trying to refer to the object instance.

How can this be achieved?

```
class Player {
    board: Board = new Board();
    pice: Pice = new Pice();

    constructor() {
        this.addKeyEvents();
    }

    addKeyEvents(): void {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyClick);
    }

    removeKeyEvents(): void {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.keyClick);
    }

    keyClick(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        console.log(this); // #document

        switch (event.keyCode) {

            // Left
            case 37:
                this.pice.move(-1, 0, this.board);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Side note, that OO design is....questionable. Having boards and pieces be a property of the player class I mean.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript) looks like a similar page just for typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to bind the function to the instance or use an arrow function to provide a proper context.

```
// Binding way.
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.addKeyEvents();
        // Bind the function to `this` context.
        this.keyClick = this.keyClick.bind(this)
    }

    addKeyEvents(): void {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.keyClick);
    }

    keyClick(event: KeyboardEvent): void { /* ... */ }
}

// Arrow function way.
class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.addKeyEvents();
    }

    addKeyEvents(): void {
        // Create an intermediary arrow function that will keep the context.
        document.addEventListener("keydown", event => this.keyClick(event));
    }

    keyClick(event: KeyboardEvent): void { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Both solutions succeeds in binding "this" to the keyClick method, but only the binding way works when also removing the event.